# How can I dump an abstract syntax tree generated by gcc into a .dot file?

Tags: gcc, graphviz, dot, abstract-syntax-tree

I think the question's title is self-explanatory, I want to dump an abstract syntax tree generated by gcc into a .dot file (Those files generated by Graphviz) because then I want to view it in a .png file or similar. Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are two methods, both including two steps

1. Using GCC internal vcg support

   1. Compile your code (say test.c) with vcg dumps

      `gcc -fdump-tree-vcg -g test.c`
   2. Use any third party tool to get dot output from vcg

      `graph-easy test.c.006t.vcg --as_dot`
2. Compile with raw dumps and then preprocess them with some scripts to form dot files (like in [this useful article](http://digitocero.com/en/blog/exporting-and-visualizing-gccs-abstract-syntax-tree-ast))

Both methods have their own good and bad sides -- with first you can really get only one dump of AST before gimple translation, but it is easy. With second you may convert any raw dump to dot-format, but you must support scripts, that is overhead.

What to prefer -- is on your own choice.

---

UPD: times are changing. Brand new option for gcc 4.8.2 makes it possible to generate dot files immediately. Just supply:

```
gcc test.c -fdump-tree-all-graph
```

and you will get a plenty of already formatted for you dot files:

```
test.c.008t.lower.dot
test.c.012t.cfg.dot
test.c.016t.ssa.dot
... etc ...
```

Please be sure to use new versions of GCC with this option.

Comment: Please update or check your answer: GCC 4.8.2 says `cc1: error: unrecognized command line option '-fdump-tree-vcg'`.

Comment: Thank you for notice, updated answer. Newer versions of GCC make things a lot easier.

Comment: Strictly speaking all `-fdump-tree-XXX` except the first one are SSA IR, not AST. And yes `-fdump-tree-vcg` is not longer available.

Answer (score 11):

According to the man page, you can get this information via `-fdump-` command.

Let's look at a dummy example:

```
// main.c

int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int main(void) {
    if (sum(8, 10) < 20) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

For gcc 7.3.0:

```
gcc -fdump-tree-all-graph main.c -o main
```

There are a lot of options to get the necessary information. Check out the manual for this info.

After that, you'll get many files. Some of them with .dot respresentation(graph option is used):

```
main.c.003t.original
main.c.004t.gimple
main.c.006t.omplower
...
main.c.011t.cfg
main.c.011t.cfg.dot
...
```

With GraphViz we can retrieve a pretty-printed graph for each function:

```
dot -Tpng main.c.011t.cfg.dot -o main.png
```

You'll get something like this:
[main.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qB7r.png)

There are a lot of developer options which can help you understand how compiler process your file at a low level: [GCC Developer Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Developer-Options.html)