# Make control flow graph (CFG) visible

Tags: clang, llvm, control-flow-graph

Since I need to generate source-level CFG, I used `CFG::buildCFG` from libclang and can get the following example output:

```
 [B0 (EXIT)]
   Preds (2): B1 B2


 [B1]
   1: n->l->x = n->x
   2: traverse(n->l)
   3: traverse(n->r)
   4: return;
   Preds (1): B3
   Succs (1): B0


 [B2]
   1: return;
   Preds (1): B3
   Succs (1): B0


 [B3]
   T: if <null expr>
   Preds (1): B4
   Succs (2): B2 B1


 [B4 (ENTRY)]
   Succs (1): B3
```

But I cannot use `opt` to generate dot file for visible CFG.

So, how can I convert the aforementioned output to visible CFG (i.e., dot file)?

Comment: Why not generate the llvm ir or bitcode for the file and use that instead??

Comment: Because source-level CFG could provide more semantic information for code analysis. In fact, I want to make a mapping between IR and source code, but I didn't find any options for showing the line number of source code in the IR CFG.

Comment: checkout https://stackoverflow.com/q/54162940/8925535